# How do I run a TCL script on files from my file manager?

Tags: tcl, desktop-integration

I'm working on a simple TCL script that makes a few Tk dialogs appear and then compresses a file given by argv. It works just fine from the terminal by running "./script file", but since it's a graphical wrapper for a command-line utility, I want it to run from the right-click menu in a file manager.

I copied it to /usr/bin and used Caja's "Open With Other Application..." option on a random file (no spaces in the path), and entered the name of my script as the application to use. When I tried to open the file this way, there were no dialogs and no archive.

However when I tried to run the script from the terminal again, without the "./", it still worked.

What needs to be done to run a TCL script on a file from the right-click menu and still be platform independant?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have fixed the script in question. I don't know why the dialogs broke or why they are working now, but the archive was apparently failing to appear because the script's working directory was automatically set to my home folder by the file manager.

The code below is what I used to direct my script to the right folder. It changes the working directory to the one containing the file that the script is being run on.

```
cd [file dirname $argv]
```

Once I set that, most of my issues seemed to be resolved, and I can now continue dveloping my script.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could start with determining wether Tcl or the file manager is the problem. Write a shell script...

```
#!/bin/sh

exec rm -- "$@"
```

...make it executable with `chmod +x` and try to use it as an "other application" on a file you don't care about. If the file isn't erased, Tcl isn't to blaim.

Comment: Okay, I think all I need is the TCL equivalent of that script.